# matlab: cellfun logic

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I have a (pretty complicated - for me anyway) cellfun operation and I need a wise head to cast their eye over it to tell if is actually doing what I have intended:

```
b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(bsxfun(@times, mag(:),cross(u{1},x))),r,'UniformOutput',false);

 size(mag)

ans =

    81     3

 size(u{1})

ans =

    81     3

size(r)

ans =

     1    81
```

u and r are cell arrays. The algorithm I need:

-> take each element of u{1} and cross product those with each element of r{1}.
-> multiply the resulting 81 x 3 cell with mag (size 81 x 3).
-> take each element of u{1} and cross product those with each element of r{2}.
-> multiply the resulting 81 x 3 cell with mag (size 81 x 3).

and so on.....

I am getting the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

Error in ==> cellcross>@(x)nansum(bsxfun(@times,mag(:),cross(u{1},x))) at 2
    b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(bsxfun(@times, mag(:),cross(u{1},x))),r,'UniformOutput',false);

Error in ==> cellcross at 2
    b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(bsxfun(@times, mag(:),cross(u{1},x))),r,'UniformOutput',false);
```

where is my logic failing me? would it be easier to change mag to a cell array, like u, and then do the mulitplication using cellfun?

would also point out that removing mag:

```
b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(cross(u{1},x)),r,'UniformOutput',false);
```

works as expected, so it is a problem with multiplying the result by u.

***edit for gunthers comment:***

Let's just say I have two objects u and r - both are cell

```
u =

1 1 0              1st element
2 2 0              2nd element
3 3 0              3rd element

r =

3 3 0
2 2 0
1 1 0
```

all I want to do is:

```
cross(u{1},r{1})
```

= cross([1 1 0],[3,3,0]) + cross([2 2 0],[2,2,0]) + cross([3 3 0],[1,1,0])

Then repeat:

```
 sum(cross(u{1},r{2}))
 sum(cross(u{1},r{3}))
 . 
 .
 . 
 .
```

Comment: it's not easy to go through your words, can you add a loop example which does what you want? If you have the loop, that's most of the time easy to convert to a `cell/array/...fun` call (assuming no recursion, interdependence, etc.)

Comment: @GUnther please see my edited post (edit for GUnther)

Comment: @brucezepplin Is there any particular reason that you are trying to use `cellfun` rather than a loop?  It looks like this may be a situation where a for loop will result in cleaner, easier to understand/debug code.  Additionally, it is certainly possible that a for loop will execute just as fast (if not faster) than `cellfun`.  (Obviously you would want to use tic/toc or the MATLAB Profiler to see if this is true for your particular use case)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tough for me to check through the entire thing and make sure the result is correct, but to the first approximation it looks like the only problem is that your cross product is failing because you're flattening `mag` by using `mag(:)` causing it to be 243x1, like so

```
>> size(mag(:))
ans =
243     1
>> size(mag)
ans =
81     3
```

That is causing your `@times` product to fail, as your error indicates.  So the altered call is

```
cellfun(@(x) nansum(bsxfun(@times, mag,cross(u{1},x))),r,'UniformOutput',false)
```